# JQuery fadeto animation with callback problem

Tags: jquery, fade, jquery-callback

Here's my code:

```
function hideColumnAndShowOther(columnToHide, columnToShow) {
$(columnToHide).fadeTo("slow", 0.0, function() {
                       $(columnToShow).fadeIn("slow");
                       });
}
```

In this case the callback function isn't called. I have used the firebug tool to get the root of the problem. In the callback function the 'columnToShow' variable is not present. I think it is logical because it is a separate block, but how can I solve this then? Do you have any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show where/how you use this code. What type of element is columnToHide?

Comment: columnToHide is a css id element, it is like " #columnToShow " and I use this code when an anchor is clicked.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/EqxsK/

Comment: Hi. Just check this please? http://jsfiddle.net/3ecp9/2/ Its your code and it works on chrome and IE (on jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the columnToShow variable is out of scope. It means nothing at that point. Instead try $(this).fadeIn("slow").

The $(this) refers to the element that you have just faded as the callback function is attached to that element.

EDIT: (misread the question)

If you change it something like the following it should work.

```
function hideColumnAndShowOther(columnToHide, columnToShow) {
    var showColumn = columnToShow;
    $(columnToHide).fadeTo("slow", 0.0,
        function() {
           $(showColumn).fadeIn("slow");
        });
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't solve my problem... I would like to fadein the columnToShow when fadeTo is finished.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. But the reason is still correct that the variables are now out of scope.

Comment: If you create a new variables like var showColumn = columnToShow before you fadeOut the other column, then you can use showColumn in the callback.

Comment: yea the first thing I did was use a global var but then your code works on jsFiddle without any changes? Or it doesn't work in browsers?

Comment: I tried it in firefox and safari and it isn't working, but with this var thing, it is working.

Comment: I think this works in all browsers. Just quickly tested it in IE6+, chrome and firefox.
Basically the var showColumn becomes global inside that main function, while the parameters get forgotten as they are not passed to the callback.

Comment: @laurencek you mean his original code right? something is amiss! lol